# When initializing a structure with the brace notation, does GCC zero-initialize its padding?

Tags: c, gcc

Does gcc zero the 3 padding bytes after `c.b` ?

```
struct {
   int a;
   char b;
} c = { 1, 2};
```

Comment: The language doesn't require anything special to be done to the padding.

Comment: Why do you only care about GCC?

Comment: @Barmar I only use gcc

Comment: @yuanjianpeng The real question is why do you care at all. That padding may not even exist, as far as the language is concerned, or it may turn to be 7 bytes next time you run the program. If that matters to you, then it's no longer "padding" but part of the relevant data.

Comment: I use the variable `c` as the hash key, with the size `sizeof(c)`, if the padding is undefined, then this usage has bug

Comment: @yuanjianpeng: Yes, that approach is not correct.

Comment: C11 [§6.2.6 Representation of types ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p6): _When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values.51) The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation._ (And the footnote 51) _Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits._

Comment: See also [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: When a question asks what a particular C compiler does, citing the language standard does not answer it. A statement that GCC does not provide any further guarantees than the standard in this regard would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  With gcc 10.1 on x86-64 with `-O2`, this code ([also on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aRg_Uj))

```
struct foo  {
   int a;
   char b;
};

void blah(struct foo *p);

void foo(void) {
    struct foo c = { 1, 2};
    blah(&c);
}
```

compiles to this assembly

```
foo:
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $1, 8(%rsp)
        movb    $2, 12(%rsp)
        call    blah
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

You can see that the last three bytes are not initialized.

Comment: how if init like this `struct foo c = {0}; `

Comment: @yuanjianpeng: In that case I think the padding bytes must be zeroed.  C17 6.7.9 (21): "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an
aggregate, [...] the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as
objects that have static storage duration."  And 6.7.9 (10) explains that when an aggregate is initialized implicitly, the padding is initialized to zero bits.